# Reading input from a text file and outputting the text to the screen in c++

Tags: c++, io, text-files

I'm a new student of the c++ language and I'm having trouble understanding...well, frankly, a whole lot of things.  I've been given this assignment to read text from a text file and output it to the screen, and I'm having quite a bit of trouble.  I've spent several hours on this now already researching and testing, and this is the code that I've got so far, and it's not working, and I'm not really sure why.  Any and all help or insights anyone would be willing to share with me would be very much appreciated.  I'm sorry I don't recall all the errors I've encountered as I worked on this by name...but I assure you there were plenty of them.  Like trying to use "fopen" in my compiler...it didn't like that, so I tried "fopen_s" like it suggested, but then it said that it wouldn't accept any arguments anymore...then I found that I needed to add "#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" as a header(?) file at the top of the program, and that problem did get solved and the program actually compiled...but then it gave me a fatal error, not sure what I did that was so fatal, but there you are.  Please help.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *pf;
    char ch;
    pf = fopen("C:\\lowerCase\anyOldTextFile.txt", "r");
    feof(pf);
    if (pf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(pf))
        {
            ch = fgetc(pf);
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
        fclose(pf);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: In addition to helping me make this work, if anyone feels inspired to help me understand how this all works I would really appreciate it.  I don't know that I'm really understanding...a whole lot of things.  Anything you feel willing to teach me about the language and/or about this aspect of the language specifically I would really very much appreciate.  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest just googling for C++ File IO... none of this is really C++ code. You'd want [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) to open files and read from them.

Comment: That sounds like a Visual Studio warning. They have their own "safer" versions of the standard library functions, but you can disable the checks. You should put the define in project settings > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor definitions. Ignoring that, the code you posted compiles.

Comment: Get a good C++ book. Learning it from random internet forums is not productive. There's a lot of extremely bad advice out there.

Comment: "Unable to open the file" is one of the most useless error messages imaginable.  `man perror`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which I pasted from [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/):

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

I didn't test this code, but it looks fine. They also explain the code on the website. I suggest visiting that page and reading all of it. Then you should be able to understand how this is working.